# Dynamics CRM 2011 - Field deleted after adding to view

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

First of all, forgive me if this is a duplicate question, however, I've looked for the answer to this problem for two days now with no luck, including the SO community.

I'm new to my job and I was tasked with making changes to a client's MS Dynamics.  They wanted  an additional field added to the Opportunity entity for a "Topic Category".  It was designed to be an option set and be available on multiple entities so I created a global option set for the task.  On the Opportunity entity itself, I created a new option set field and used the global option set for the options.

I'm able to add it to the form fine, however, when I try to add it to the views I run into an error saying that the field has been deleted and that I need to remove the field before I can save the view.

The exact error is:

> This field has been deleted.  To use or save this saved view, you must remove the field.
>
> [Image of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k8QV.jpg)

**EDIT:**
After following the tracing suggestions, I was able to produce this in the error log.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Invalid FetchXml on SavedQuery.Update.Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2140991216</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>Invalid FetchXml on SavedQuery.Update.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2014-01-15T18:03:14.1961051Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault>
    <ErrorCode>-2147220733</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDetails xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Message>The column, fetchxml, has invalid fetch.  Error : 'SystemUser' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'bsb_topiccategory'.</Message>
    <Timestamp>2014-01-15T18:03:14.1961051Z</Timestamp>
    <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  </InnerFault>
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

This was created when trying to save the view with the faulty attribute attached to it.  Saving it seemed to be the only way to pop an error out to the log.  All of that being said, I'm not entirely sure how to handle the error.  I've looked through the entities and couldn't find a systemuser entity.  Maybe I'm just missing something?

Comment: SystemUser is the User record.  You can view these under Settings -> Administration -> Users.  As suspected you have an attribute bsb_topiccategory being used in the View that either no longer exists on the SystemUser entity or you don't have the required permissions to see it.  If you're a System Administrator you need to decide on the correct approach for the business of either removing it from the view or adding it back onto the SystemUser entity.  I suspect the removal from the view will be the likely outcome.

Comment: @DazLewis bsb_topiccategory is the option set that I created initially to place on the form and view.  How can it be deleted when I can plainly see it inside the fields list of the entity I'm trying to edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but in case anyone runs into the same problems I did, I want to make sure the answer is known.

After looking at the permissions for the user I was logged in as, I noticed that the user only had administrative access.  I was confused at first (again, my first forray into CRM) as I always thought of an Administrator with someone with "end all, beat all" access.  This isn't the case with CRM.  In order to make changes to the views, the user you're using needs to have **"Full" access while having the "System-Administrator" role**.

The answer seems incredibly stupid now that the problem is resolved, but if this helps anyone, I'll be a happy camper.

Answer (score 1):

It maybe that an attribute has been deleted for an existing column in the view which has nothing to do with your optionset.  That missing attribute would be validated when you try and make changes though.

In theory this should never happen as the system should prevent you from deleting an attribute that has dependencies (the view in this case).  I'd still check all of the existing columns in the view do indeed exist as attributes on the entity.

If this does prove to be correct it looks like someone may have deleted the attribute directly from the database!

Comment: When you say attribute, you're talking about other fields themselves?

Comment: If {attributes = fields} then I did a check and can verify that they're all there.  Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Yes attributes = fields.  Have you tried adding it to another view to confirm if it's an issue with that particular attribute or added a different attribute to the view causing problems?

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think to try that before.  It appears as if all attributes that weren't on the view before the customizations have the same error.

Comment: This sort of confirms what I was thinking in that it's not an issue with the attribute(s) you're adding but one that is already on there. I'd try turning on logging at this point, repro the error and check the logs for any specifics of the errant attribute.

Comment: Turns out that tracing has been turned on the whole time.  Is there a specific file in the trace logs that I should look at, or even something specific to this type of problem that I could search for?

Comment: @amusick Use the TraceLogViewer to make finding errors and the such much easier :http://www.stunnware.com/crm2/topic.aspx?id=TraceLogViewer

Comment: No specific issue.  Get yourself a copy of CrmDiagTool2011.exe and Trace Viewer.  Turn on Verbose, perform the action to repro, turn off logging (to prevent being swamped with data).  In the first instance I'd then search the log file generated for the logical name of the view you tried to save.  Hopefully you should see the name of the specific attribute causing problems.  An alternative to checking the logs is to try and recreate the view adding columns one by one or remove the columns one by one from the existing view.

Answer (score 0):

This is a total stab in the dark, but have you attempted to publish all customizations?  You can delete something, but not publish the change and it'll still look like it's there.

Comment: Yeah I thought that might have been the problem, so I did try this.  Also, the problem is the reverse of what you have mentioned (eg: trying to add a column to the view that says deleted upon adding not trying to delete a field and it still showing on the view).